# Functional Reactive Programming in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Are there any libraries written for Scala enabling Functional Reactive Programming?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11619680/403455

Answer (score 43):

See also Odersky et al.'s paper "[Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887)". It explains the library [Scala.React](https://github.com/ingoem/scala-react), which was developed for the paper.

Comment: This paper is actually very good. It really made me understand what is all the fuzz in FRP all about...

Comment: [here](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887) is new version.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11619680/403455

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I provided [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13236109/615784) for inverting the control of state using Scala's delimited continuations, not just inversion-of-control of caller/callee, which afaics that paper and Scala.React don't do.

Comment: [What's the status of Scala.React?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095728/whats-the-status-of-scala-react) https://github.com/ingoem/scala-react

Answer (score 12):

There's reactive -- http://github.com/nafg/reactive.
The repository currently contains two projects. reactive-core is a standalone FRP library. reactive-web builds on it to make it very easy to make very dynamic and interactive Lift webapps.

Comment: I tried reactive-core in a Swing GUI and found it quite pleasant to use. The biggest pain is actually language related -- Scala could use nicer syntax for applicatives.

Comment: @Owen - that's interesting. Where do you use applicatives? P.S. Do you have a Swing bridge that's shareable?

Comment: `Signal` is an applicative. And I didn't use any sort of bridge; I just mixed reactive code in with Swing code -- a little messy since the swing components are so stateful, but usable. The whole thing will be on github eventually.

Comment: How is Signal an applicative?

Comment: `pure` is a constant signal, and `ap` is doing a `zip` followed by a `map`. So if say I have a signal `x` and a signal `y` and I want a signal `x + y`, `x zip y map { case (x, y) => x+y }` is like scalaz `(x |@| y)(_ + _)`.

Comment: Ah thanks for the info. If you like, feel free to open an issue to add applicative syntax.

Comment: @Owen just added it. https://github.com/nafg/reactive/commit/593a7710dc217501afcc4fc6d167114b7bff8b10

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava Functional Reactive Programming library for the JVM, developed by Netflix.

Comment: Rx (Reactive Extensions) is not "functional reactive programming" in the FRP sense, although you could argue that it is both functional and reactive in the general sense.

Answer (score 9):

There is [Scala.Rx](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx) by Li Haoyi. In short, it aims to be a simpler, easy-to-use and more interoperable reimagination of (parts of) Scala.React.

Don't be misled by the Rx suffix. Scala.Rx has little to do with Reactive Extensions from .NET. Scala.Rx does not focus so much on asynchrony and event streams as rather time-varying values and the expression of functional dependencies with automatic change propagation.

Answer (score 8):

I don't Scala so don't know how good these are but here is a blog with comments that talk about FRP in scala: [Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) in Scala (Fresca, ScalaFX)](http://www.nabble.com/Functional-Reactive-Programming-%28FRP%29-in-Scala-%28Fresca%2C-ScalaFX%29-td23838581.html) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/8uuls/what_is_functional_reactive_programming/) is the reddit that shows a stackoverflow conversation that led me to the above link.

> > I'd have a few questions about the FRP capabilities in Scala. What is
> >     the current status of [ScalaFX](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala-experimental/trunk/sfx/trunk)? 
> >     isn't updated since 3 months... Is it currently usable?
>
> It is definitely usable, there is just
>   not an official release yet.
>
> > Are there any other FRP frameworks coming up (e.g. Fresca reborn)?
>
> Fresca was my very first attempt at
>   FRP in Scala. SFX as it is currently 
>   in trunk improves on Fresca in several
>   aspects and as such can be seen  as a
>   successor to Fresca.

Answer (score 7):

Coursera [Principles of Reactive Programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive) course promotes [RxScala](http://rxscala.github.io/).

> RxScala brings Reactive Extensions to Scala. Rx was first implemented
>   for .NET, and is now being implemented in Java. The RxScala project is
>   an adaptor for RxJava. Its code is in a subdirectory the RxJava
>   repository.
>
> This library is not yet finished. You have to expect breaking changes
>   in future versions.

Answer (score 5):

There is scala-reactive: http://github.com/erikrozendaal/scala-reactive

It is inspired by Microsoft's Reactive Extensions library, with an Observable trait taking the place of IObservable, and tailored to the Scala collections API as much Rx is to the LINQ API.

Answer (score 0):

You have many many libraries. Here you have a list of many of them https://github.com/politrons/reactiveScala