# What's the status of Scala.React?

Tags: scala, frp

I just read [Deprecating the Observer Pattern](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) and found it absolutely fascinating.

What's the status of the Scala.React package described in the document? I found one tarball of a snapshot of Scala.React but there doesn't seem to be much documentation or active maintenance. I also found ScalaFX, which looks like it might be related to reactive programming, but is similarly unmaintained.

Are there any projects out there that build on the ideas in this paper to create a GUI framework based on reactives?

Comment: Any information on the latest work in this area?  I also read the paper and am interested in experimenting, but it seems to be difficult to find an actively maintained and documented project.  I know of Scala.React, ScalaFX, SFX (same as ScalaFX?), and Fresca, but I can find no indication that work on these frameworks is still underway. A recent related question on the mailing list seems to have gone unanswered as well.

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATED**: As [William Harvey points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10635684/455615), there is recent progress!

---

Like you, I have an intense interest in the project, so I creep these pages every few weeks. :)

https://github.com/ingoem

http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/

https://codereview.scala-lang.org/fisheye/user/imaier

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/search?q=imaier

Comment: Looks like there is no scala-react repository any more. :-(

Comment: Oops! Didn't notice that there never was one. Still, sad that there hasn't been any further update. Looks like a discontinued project now.

Answer (score 16):

Good news!  It looks like  Ingo Maier and Martin Odersky published a new technical report this year (2012) with some updates to Scala.React.  The new code has been available on GitHub for about two weeks.

Relevant links:

Technical Report (2012):  http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887

GitHub:  https://github.com/ingoem/scala-react

Comment: It's 2016. And there is still only single commit. (

Answer (score 7):

Some similar projects:

- http://github.com/nafg/reactive
- https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx
- https://github.com/stefan-hoeck/dire
- https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava (in Java but has scala bindings)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054179/functional-reactive-programming-in-scala for more.

Answer (score 6):

The only project that I currently know of is Naftoli Gugenheim's [reactive web](http://reactive-web-demo.nafg.cloudbees.net/) project, which he announced in [this thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/ANN-reactive-web-td3233480.html) on the scala mailing list. The code is hosted at http://github.com/nafg/reactive

Comment: Isn't it based on scala-react?

Comment: @pedrofurla no it's not, though it was written after I despaired of it working soon enough.