# Example of using Scala delimited continuations for GUI programming

Tags: user-interface, scala, listener, continuations

I guess Scala delimited continuations can be successfully used to implement GUI event listeners with any Java GUI framework (e.g. Swing). Is there any simple but non-trivial example of using the continuations for GUI programming?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is [scala.react](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/).

Alternatively, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095728/whats-the-status-of-scala-react) question.

Answer (score 1):

I should check out scala.react, but so far, I've been using scala.swing.{ Publisher, Reactor } for doing my own event listeners. It's working well for me.

Comment: Do you use continuations for your GUI development?