# How should FRP work at the top level?

Tags: user-interface, scala, programming-languages, functional-programming, frp

I have been experimenting with creating a [Functional Reactive Programming framework for Scala](http://www.github.com/oetzi/echo). One thing at the moment I am confused about is how current implementations have dealt with representing behaviours at the top level. To explain what I mean I'll give an example. Say I have a JPanel and I want to do this:

```
 JPanel panel = new Panel()
 panel.setBackground(new Behaviour(time => Color.red))
```

Although the color is static here we want the panel background to update when the value of the Behaviour updates. The way I have done it so far is to essentially create a discretized Behaviour using Events (accessible via a `changes` function on Behaviours). This is basically just an event source that occurs whenever the Behaviour changes. Using this the implementation of setBackground here would be:

```
def setBackground(color : Behaviour[Color]) {
  super.setBackground(color.now)
  color.changes.each(change => super.setBackground(change))
}
```

This feels kind of messy. Does anyone have any suggestions of whether this is a bad approach or not? I have been looking at Elliott's [Push-Pull FRP](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/) today and it feels like I might be going in the right direction but getting lost somewhere.

EDIT: If no one has a definite clear cut solution then ideas/thoughts would be great!

Comment: I'm willing to add some bounty to a question that asks a translation of the paper to Scala.

Comment: @ziggystar I agree that would be amazing. One of main problems with researching FRP is having to crawl through unfamiliar Haskell syntax. Would that be correct to ask for on Stack Overflow though?

Comment: Maybe the only point against it is that questions should be reasonably scoped. Thus answers should not get too lengthy. But I think the question itself is ok for SO. But translating the paper on a reasonable level takes some time. I'd more suspect it to be posted on a blog.

Comment: You might get your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095728/whats-the-status-of-scala-react

Comment: @Szabolcs the problem there is that Scala.react isn't really FRP. Thanks for the link anyway though.

Comment: @Conal Sorry for the misspelling :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. In Conal Elliott's original vision, behaviors are *continuous* in time, so they don't come with a function `changes` that indicates when they change.

   The behavior that returns the current clock time would be the prime example of a continuous behavior. It doesn't support a `changes` function, unless you specify a time step ("it generates a 'change' event every nanosecond"). But the point of "continuous" is the lack of a time step.

   In my view, this means that behaviors in Conal's sense don't support incremental updates at all. In my [reactive-banana](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana) library, I have introduced a new data type `Discrete` that is some kind of hybrid between behaviors and events. See the documentation of the module [Reactive.Banana.Incremental](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.4.2.0/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Incremental.html) for more details on the rationale.
2. You are probably annoyed by having wrap each and every GUI function like `setBackground` to make it work with behaviors instead of plain values. This is were higher-order functions really shine: the wrapper is always the same, you can express it as a higher order function; here a Haskell version:

   ```
   set' :: Property a -> Behavior a -> IO ()
   set' property behavior = do
        set property (now behavior)
        each (\a -> set property a) (changes behavior)          

   each f event = reactimate (fmap f event) -- helper definition

   example = set' background red
   ```

   Of course, this relies a lot on Haskell's syntax and may not be as pleasant in Scala, where some functions are written before their first argument.

Comment: I had though about a `set` like function and yes it isn't quite as nice in Scala (mainly due to the fact the `background` property and others are generally not available from outside the class). However it looks like its the best way to do it.

Also, just to confirm that the Behaviours in my implementation are actually continuous. The `changes` function returns an EventSource that listens for changes to the Behaviour (its more of a utility than anything). 

What is the `reactimate` function here out of interest (and is `changes` referring to my `changes`)?

Comment: @Oetzi: Well, the behavior that returns the current clock time would be the prime example of a continuous behavior. You can't really write a `changes` function for it, because it changes "all the time".

Comment: @Oetzi: The `reactimate` function is part your `.each` function; the latter decomposes into an `fmap` and a `reactimate` part. The `changes` functions are supposed to be the same.

Comment: I understand that technically the `changes` function isn't accurate. However how would you represent the color behaviour here is what I'm asking. Would you use a Discrete instead of a Behaviour?

Comment: @Oetzi: Yes, I would use the `Discrete` type. Then again, there's also the option of trying to implement Behaviors in a way that uses a `changes` function internally for efficiency but does not export it; this would avoid the unfortunate duplication of functionality by the `Discrete` type. Or you can make `Behavior` discrete by default, but that complicates the semantics a bit (no more continuous `Behavior a = Time -> a`). It's up to you and your taste, I'd say.

Comment: The first way is how I currently do it. Thanks for all the thoughts!