# Is there a generalized approach to handling notifications of changes from large persistent data structure?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming

First the motivation for this question: anyone who uses persistent data structures and a gui runs into this problem. So, my questions is kind of: do people just work it out on a case by case basis, or are their libraries, utilities, frameworks, something that abstracts the general case to make it easier to do.

The specific language I'm targeting is Scala, but I think this is a general question related to persistent data structures.

Let's say you have a large data structure displayed in a complex gui with trees, tables, property sheets, etc. Various user or system actions result in modifications to the data structure.

Is there a general strategy for handling notifications to tell the gui to update itself?

One of the intriguing ideas with persistent data structures is one could handle undo/redo by just switching between roots. That works for the data, but is there a general mechanism for telling listeners (eg. a gui) about the change if one were to switch roots?

My understanding is that it needs to be incremental--I need to know what changed. I can't just tell everything to do a complete refresh of the gui since that could be very expensive (and some controls don't handle it well (or at all) because of maintaining gui state).

Comment: Your diverse questions interest me.  Can you provide any insight into the larger task?  I'm just (overly) curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd update the GUI at the same time you switch roots, since if the structure is truly persistent, then any change deep down in the structure will incur a new root. That, however, will be done imperatively (or in some kind of monadic construction; I've never done GUI programming in Haskell).

E.g., if your GUI code is imperative/OO but uses a persistent `State` structure:

```
// poor man's zipper for unbounded undo/redo
var curState : State
var prevStates : List[State]
var nextStates : List[State]

def undo = {
    val prev = prevStates.head
    prevStates = prevStates.tail
    nextStates = curState :: nextStates
    curState = prev
    updateGui(curState)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see I missed something important in the question. The guis I have worked with generally expect incremental updates. Refreshing the entire gui could be extremely expensive. The call to updateGui(curState)--that's the magic I'm trying to figure out how to do that in a reasonable fashion.

Comment: @taotree: the obvious solution would be to store the differences between states (e.g. `UserAction` objects, or some transformation of them) with the actual undo list.

Comment: Yes, one could roll one's own solution for that. My question is if there is some commonly used detailed approach. This is a path many have already gone down I would expect, and I'm wondering if someone has already designed a good solution for it as opposed to me reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

See this question about [Functional Reactive Programming in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054179/functional-reactive-programming-in-scala). And also see the [Cells menifesto](http://smuglispweeny.blogspot.com/2008/02/cells-manifesto.html) and the [Wikipedia article about FRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) for background.

And read the paper "Deprecating Observer Pattern using Scala.React": http://lamp.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf mentioned on an answer by magicduncan on the above SO question.