# Why should the observer pattern be deprecated?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I've noticed that my dependency injected, observer-pattern-heavy code (using Guava's [EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)) is often significantly more difficult to debug than code I've written in the past without these features.  Particularly when trying to determine when and why observer code is being called.

Martin Oderski and friends wrote a lengthy paper with an especially alluring title, ["Deprecating the Observer Pattern"](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/148043/files/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf) and I have not yet made the time to read it.

I'd like to know what is so wrong with the observer pattern and so much better about the (proposed or other) alternatives to lead such bright people to write this paper.

As a start, I did find one (entertaining) critique of the paper [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111116204240/http://java.dzone.com/articles/few-thoughts-deprecating).

Comment: Discussed here too ... http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4028

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Quoting directly from [the paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~imaier/pub/DeprecatingObserversTR2010.pdf):

To illustrate the precise problems of the observer pattern,
we start with a simple and ubiquitous example: mouse dragging.
The following example traces the movements of the
mouse during a drag operation in a `Path` object and displays
it on the screen. To keep things simple, we use Scala closures
as observers.

```scala
var path: Path = null
val moveObserver = { (event: MouseEvent) =>
   path.lineTo(event.position)
   draw(path)
}
control.addMouseDownObserver { event =>
   path = new Path(event.position)
   control.addMouseMoveObserver(moveObserver)
}
control.addMouseUpObserver { event =>
   control.removeMouseMoveObserver(moveObserver)
   path.close()
   draw(path)
}
```

The above example, and as we will argue the observer
pattern as defined in [25] in general, violates an impressive
line-up of important software engineering principles:

**Side-effects** Observers promote side-effects. Since observers
are stateless, we often need several of them to simulate
a state machine as in the drag example. We have to save
the state where it is accessible to all involved observers
such as in the variable `path` above.

**Encapsulation** As the state variable `path` escapes the scope
of the observers, the observer pattern breaks encapsulation.

**Composability** Multiple observers form a loose collection
of objects that deal with a single concern (or multiple,
see next point). Since multiple observers are installed at
different points at different times, we can’t, for instance,
easily dispose them altogether.

**Separation of concerns** The above observers not only trace
the mouse path but also call a drawing command, or
more generally, include two different concerns in the
same code location. It is often preferable to separate the
concerns of constructing the path and displaying it, e.g.,
as in the model-view-controller (MVC) [30] pattern.

**Scalablity** We could achieve a separation of concerns in our
example by creating a class for paths that itself publishes
events when the path changes. Unfortunately, there is no
guarantee for data consistency in the observer pattern.
Let us suppose we would create another event publishing
object that depends on changes in our original path, e.g.,
a rectangle that represents the bounds of our path. Also
consider an observer listening to changes in both the
path and its bounds in order to draw a framed path. This
observer would manually need to determine whether the
bounds are already updated and, if not, defer the drawing
operation. Otherwise the user could observe a frame on
the screen that has the wrong size (a glitch).

**Uniformity** Different methods to install different observers
decrease code uniformity.

**Abstraction** There is a low level of abstraction in the example.
It relies on a heavyweight interface of a control
class that provides more than just specific methods to install
mouse event observers. Therefore, we cannot abstract
over the precise event sources. For instance, we
could let the user abort a drag operation by hitting the escape
key or use a different pointer device such as a touch
screen or graphics tablet.

**Resource management** An observer’s life-time needs to be
managed by clients. Because of performance reasons,
we want to observe mouse move events only during a
drag operation. Therefore, we need to explicitly install
and uninstall the mouse move observer and we need to
remember the point of installation (control above).

**Semantic distance** Ultimately, the example is hard to understand
because the control flow is inverted which results
in too much boilerplate code that increases the semantic
distance between the programmers intention and
the actual code.

[25] E. Gamma, R. Helm, R. Johnson, and J. Vlissides. Design
patterns: elements of reusable object-oriented software.
Addison-Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc., Boston, MA,
USA, 1995. ISBN 0-201-63361-2.

Comment: I wonder if the weaknesses listed here are inherent to the observer pattern. I've just read through a description of the MobX library, which I believe uses the observer pattern, but that seems to address a good number of the issues described above. For example, it seems that MobX does include a guarantee of the consistency and "freshness" of values, and the order in which they update. See [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-fundamental-principles-behind-mobx-7a725f71f3e8). Curious what others think...

Comment: I won't comment on all of them, but many can be alleviated by using the correct pattern, i.e. Change Manager for the Observer in the case above where you are defining a path.  Change Manager is a Mediator.  So I think your example is a bit of a straw man.

Comment: The link in the answer is not accessible anymore... but the one in the question is (and supposedly they should be the same)

Comment: Has anyone an example how this case is better using the now recommended `PropertyChangeEvent`

Comment: @jeff thank you.  what pattern do you prefer to observer? Delegation through closure?

Answer (score 21):

I believe the Observer pattern has the standard drawbacks that come with decoupling things. The Subject gets decoupled from Observer but you cannot just look at its source code and find out who observes it. Hardcoded dependencies are usually easier to read and think about but they are harder to modify and reuse. It's a tradeoff.

As to the paper, it does not address the Observer pattern itself but a particular usage of it. In particular: multiple stateless Observer objects per single object being observed. This has the obvious drawback of the separate observers needing to synchronize with each other (*"Since observers are stateless, we often need several of them to simulate
a state machine as in the drag example. We have to save
the state where it is accessible to all involved observers
such as in the variable path above.*")

The above drawback is specific to this kind of usage, not to the Observer pattern itself. You could as well create a single (stateful!) observer object that implements all the `OnThis`, `OnThat`,`OnWhatever` methods and get rid of the problem of simulating a state machine across many stateless objects.

Comment: But the observers in the example *do* clearly have side effects as mentioned in your quote. (See all the manipulations of the `path` def).

Answer (score 9):

I will be brief because I'm new to the topic (and didn't read that specific article yet).

Observer Pattern is intuitively wrong: The Object to be observed knows who is observing (Subject<>--Observer).
That is against real-life (in event-based scenarios). If I scream, I have no idea who is listening; if a lightening, hits the floor... lightning doesn't know that there is a floor till it hits!. Only Observers know what they can observe.

When this kind of of things happen then software use to be a mess -because constructed against  our way of thinking-.
It is as if and object knew what other objects can call his methods.

IMO a layer such as "Environment" is the one in charge of taking the events and notifying the affected. (OR mixes the event and the generator of that event)

Event-Source (Subject) generates events to the Environment. Environment delivers the event to the Observer. Observer could register to the kind of events that affects him or it is actually defined in the Environment. Both possibilities make sense (but I wanted to be brief).

In my understanding the Observer Pattern puts together environment & subject.

PS. hate to put in paragraphs abstract ideas! :P

Comment: Here http://www.marco.panizza.name/dispenseTM/slides/exerc/eventNotifier/eventNotifier.html
I have found the diagram which basically says the same: 
-Publisher (Subject)
-Subscriber (Object)
-EventService (Environment)
(1998)
After all "common sense" leads to it and one way or another we implement these kind of middle-layer when programming. Problem comes when the Pattern motivates or misleads.

Comment: Subjects do not know their observers (perhaps only through base class). The Design Pattern book also mention a change manager. This is somewhat similar as your environment. Imho the Observer pattern is great for notification of (independent) GUI elements, but the pattern has some serious drawbacks as well: spurious notifications while subject or business layer is not in a consistent state; subject changes by a observer during a notification update.

Comment: A few points here, the subject does not know any thing about the observers, we can achieve this by abstract interface.