# Where to put the email sending?

Tags: php, email, orm, single-responsibility-principle

There is a "news" system, when a "new" is added, an email should be sent too.

```
class ModelNews extends NewsORM
{
    public function add ($new)
    {
        INSERT INTO newstable
    }
}
```

but I also need to send an email, so:

```
class ModelNews extends NewsORM
{
    public function add ($new)
    {
        INSERT INTO newstable
        mail->send
    }
}
```

but it looks odd. It looks like SRP is violated

Comment: Maybe it should be managed in the Controller instead of the model? if ($model->add($new)) $mail->send();

Comment: but a new "news" can be added from anywhere, and that way I should always call the controller. That wouldnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like SRP is violated

It does indeed. When you need to do multiple things you can apply the open/closed principle and decouple everything.

```
interface AddNews
{
    public function add($new);
}

class SaveNews extends NewsORM implements AddNews
{
    public function add($new)
    {
        // INSERT INTO newstable
    }
}

class SendNews extends NewsORM implements AddNews
{
    public function add ($new)
    {
        //mail->send
    }
}

class AggregatorNews implements AddNews
{ 
    private $news = []; 

    public function addNews(AddNews $news)
    { 
        $this->news[] = $news; 
    } 

    public function add($new)
    { 
        foreach ($this->news as $obj) { 
            $obj->add($new); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$news = new AggregatorNews();
$news->addNews(new SaveNews);
$news->addNews(new SendNews);

$news->add('bla bla');
```

Comment: and why not simply just extends ORM? Why to add them to a list?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a listener/scheduler that could look for new records in the database and then send the email.

```
class ModelNews extends NewsORM
{
    public function add ($new)
    {
        INSERT INTO newstable
    }
}

class SendNews extends NewsListener
{
     public function listen($news) {
        mail-> send
     }
}
```

Thus SRP is not violated

Comment: but encapsulation does :) encapsulation violated. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619680/why-should-the-observer-pattern-be-deprecated

Comment: I agree. As long as the core state is not modified no harm done. However, I would leave it with the implementor the choice of the principle that one is willing to violate :-)

Answer (score 1):

make a new sendEmail function and put the code there.

and when you need it. call it in the entire app.